# AttributedString subscript loses font style after selecting text in NSTextView

Tags: nstextview, nsmutableattributedstring

I have two `NSMutableAttributedString` styles for text in my `NSTextView`. One is a font style and the other is a superscript, using `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName` shown below:

```
aVerseNumberMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: verseNumber.description, 
   attributes: [NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName:NSNumber(double: 6.0), NSFontAttributeName:NSFont(name: "Georgia", size: 12.0)!])
```

They work perfectly until I select text in the `NSTextView` and then trigger the `NSTextView` to change its text using a `NSPopUpButton`. Then the superscript font style reverts to the style of the other text. Here is all the lines of code together.

```
// Get the verse number and then add attributes
aVerseNumberMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: verseNumber.description, 
    attributes: [NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName:NSNumber(double: 6.0), NSFontAttributeName:NSFont(name: "Georgia", size: 12.0)!])

// Get the verse and then add attributes
aVerseMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: " " + book.verseText + "  ", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:NSFont(name: "Georgia", size: 20.0)!])

// Prepend the verse number to the verse
theContent.appendAttributedString(aVerseNumberMutableString)
theContent.appendAttributedString(aVerseMutableString)
```

I can see how this may happen because I'm appending the two strings together, but why does this happen only when I select the text and then trigger the content to change in the `NSTextView`?

[Video of the problem. Just look at the first superscript as I change the content before selecting text and after selecting text.](https://youtu.be/fAvLnzfWbSY)

Answer (score 1):

The issues wasn't in the creation of the attributed string. It was with how I populated the `NSTextView` with content. I was deleting the text in the view using

```
contentTextView.textStorage!.mutableString.setString("")
```

and then filling it using

```
 contentTextView.insertText(getChapterText("1"))
```

What I should have been using was `NSTextStorage` to do it all. So now instead of two lines of code I now have one.

```
contentTextView.textStorage!.setAttributedString(getChapterText("1"))
```

Now selecting text, or even just clicking inside the text view, doesn't change the style of the text like it used to.

Comment: Thanks, that solves a mystery I was trying to figure out just now :)